# Proving the distribution of union operation on the intersection of two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove $$ \left(A \cap B \right) \cup C = \left(A \cup C \right) \cap \left(B \cup C\right)$$

My attempt is the usual one : 
$$ \textrm{Let}~ x \in \left[ 
\left (
A \cap B 
\right)
\cup C
\right] $$

$$\implies x \in \left(A \cap B \right) ~\textrm{or}~ x \in C $$

$$\implies \left( x \in A ~\textrm{and}~ x \in B \right) ~\textrm{or}~ x \in C $$

The last line can be written in words as " x belongs to A and simultaneously to B or x belongs to C". Now, how to proceed logically? I'm in need of a detailed answer explaining how interpret and manipulate the statement " x belongs to A and simultaneously to B or x belongs to C ".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just reason with words instead of formulae (otherwise you reduce it to a similar statement in propositional logic):

Let $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$. This means we know that $x \in C$ or $x \in A \cap B$. If $x \in C$ then $x \in A \cup C$ and $x \in B \cup C$ too. So
$x \in (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$, in that case. Otherwise $x \in A \cap B$ and so $x \in A$ (so also in $A \cup C$) and $x \in B$ (so also in $B \cup C$, and again $x \in (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$.

The other inclusion: let $x \in (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$. So $x \in A \cup C$ and also $x \in B \cup C$. If $x \in C$ we are done as then $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$ a fortiori. So assume $x \notin C$ instead. Then $x \in A$ (otherwise $x \notin A \cup C$) and $x \in B$ (or else $x \notin B \cup C$), so $x \in A \cap B$ and hence $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$. These two cases prove the other inclusion.

The two inclusions together show equality of sets.

Comment: My question was to prove $$ \left(A \cap B \right) \cup C = \left(A \cup C \right) \cap \left(B \cup C\right)$$ . You have proved the distributivity of intersection.

Comment: @adeshmishra I changed the proof accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

$$(A∩B)∪C≡\{x:x∈(A∩B)∪C\}$$$$≡\{x:(x∈A∩B) ∨ x∈C\}$$$$≡\{x:(x∈A ∧ x∈B) ∨ x∈C\}$$$$≡\{x:(x∈A ∨ x∈C) ∧ (x∈B∨x∈C) \}$$$$≡\{x:(x∈A∪C)∩(x∈B∪C)\}$$$$≡\{x:x∈(A∪C)∩(B∪C)\}$$

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to know, why is it that?

Comment: you can show  $\left(A \cap B \right) \cup C⊆ \left(A \cup C \right) \cap \left(B \cup C\right)$ and then $ \left(A \cup C \right) \cap \left(B \cup C\right)⊆\left(A \cap B \right) \cup C$, but another easier way is to  use equivalency as I did

Answer (score 0):

Prove distributivity of 'or' over 'and'.
(P and Q) or R .iff. (P or R) and (Q or R)

Hints.
Left to right.
(P and Q) or R .implies. P or R

Right to left.
Two cases:  R and not-R.

Comment: How to do that? Or please suggest me some logic books where I can find the "distributivity of **or** over **and** "

Comment: See edit, @adeshmishra.

Comment: How $\textrm{ P and Q or R } \implies \textrm{P or R} $ ? I'm not understanding it, let's say we write $\textrm{P and Q}$ as $S$ then we've $\textrm{S or R}$ and I think we cannot break S. Please help !

Comment: Without parenthesis , @adeshmishra, P and Q or R is ambiguous.

Comment: Let's call $\left(P ~\textrm{and} ~ Q \right)$ as S, then we've $ \textrm{S or R} $. So how can we conclude that **P or R** from above?

Comment: Because, @adeshmishra, P and Q .implies. P.

Answer (score 0):

Equality amounts to reciprocal inclusion.

Below is shown the inclusion of the LHS set in the RHS set.

[image]